# how to search for a specific text with a special character in it in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

i'm trying to find and replace text in sublime text editor. For example:- `count(` to something else. But sublime is even taking text such as `gettotalcount(` as text match because it ends with `gettotal"count("`.

I tried searching so for the answer but no luck. Could someone tell me how to do that.

Comment: Use the regular expression functionality. There is a star sign when you hit CTRL+F. This will enable regular expressions. Remember to escape this symbols with "\" backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the regular expression search Ctrl + F or Cmd + F and choose the regular expression search `[]`. Then enter this in the search:

```
\bcount\(
```

`\b` is a word boundary marker, in this case stating the search must begin with following word.

`\(` escapes the parentheses.

Comment: what is that b for ?

Comment: It is a regular expression boundary marker for words